# Vuejs 3 "refs" best practice guidlines

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**Are there any best practice sources for component engineering using component refs="" within VueJs 3?**

> For example:
>
> - Should refs be used to reference components or solely for HtmlDom references?
> - Should you expose component methods to using components, i.e., Component A uses Component B; where Component B exposes MethodA, that
>   Component A calls?
> - When is it not acceptable or not recommended to use refs; and when would the use of refs be advocated for?

Comment: The question is too broad, I believe. Basically, 1) both 2) yes 3) depends on whether there are better ways to achieve a goal